# 'dict' object is not callable console err

Tags: python, api, weather

After Coping Code and Modifing it to mine (the api), i get the error which says dict object is not callable, will be appriciated if you would help, thx

`

```
city_name = city
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    channel = interaction.channel
    if x["cod"] != "404":
            y = x["main"]
            current_temperature = y["temp"]
            current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
            current_pressure = y["pressure"]
            current_humidity = y["humidity"]
            z = x["weather"]
            weather_description = z[0]["description"]
            weather_description = z[0]["description"]
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"Weather in {city_name}",
                              color=interaction.guild.me.top_role.color,
                              timestamp=interaction.message.created_at,)
            embed.add_field(name="Descripition", value=f"**{weather_description}**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Temperature(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**", inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {interaction.user.name}")
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("City not found.")
```

`

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: i have no idea, i used print statements but none of them printed.

Comment: `dict object is not callable` there must be a stack trace associated with this error. Its not something you have to specifically print out.

Comment: ```channel = interaction.channel```
@TokoLPlayz what is the type of ```interaction``` here?

Comment: i use nextcord, and i make slash commands, i define interaction as nextcord.Interaction. if thats what you are asking for.